# Disable default error parsers in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

How to disable the default error parsers in Eclipse CDT?

I made a plain C++ project.
When I try to uncheck error parsers in **Project**->**Properties**->**C/C++ Build**->**Settings**->**Error Parsers** and when I press the **Apply** button, all uncheked parsers are checked again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm I see the same behaviour. I would suggest [filing a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT).